# How to read a file and replace a string in another file using shell script in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I am try to read the value of the key from the text file. After reading it I wanted to concatenate this value with some string and replace that line in another file. Please find the below code

```
source.txt file

USERNAME='cffde308-a1f8-436f-9750-619856e70b88'
PASSWORD='XEAstplhfKNAjUg2Z2oXjIe7o9D4VW3q2dtnkoiMEP0='
```

target.js file

```
auth: {
  username: 'zfgde308-a1f8-436f-9750-619856e70b89',
  password: 'ZEAstplhfKNAjUg2Z2oXjIe7o9D4VW3q2dtnkoiMEP0=',
 },
```

I wanted to copy username and password from the source file and replace it in the config file. I tried the below code

```
#! /bin/sh
source "/opt/source/source.txt"
USER="username: '$USERNAME',"
PWD="password: '$PASSWORD',"

echo $USER
echo $PWD

sed '/username/c\$USER' target.js
sed '/password/c\$PWD' target.js
```

And the result that i get it is

```
    [l21m23 source]$ ./ClientDetailsSetup.sh
    ',ername: 'cffde308-a1f8-436f-9750-619856e70b88
    password: 'XEAstplhfKNAjUg2Z2oXjIe7o9D4VW3q2dtnkoiMEP0=',

    auth: {
      username: 'zfgde308-a1f8-436f-9750-619856e70b89',
$PWD
    },
```

If some help at the earliest to resolve this issue would be of great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
source "/opt/source/source.txt"
USERN="username: '$USERNAME',"
PWD="password: '$PASSWORD',"

echo $USERN
echo $PWD

sed -i "s/username:.*/$USERN/" target.js
sed -i "s/password:.*/$PWD/" target.js
```

There were a few issues:

- `USER` is a reserved shell variable so you have to give it a different name
- your sed script needs `s/.../.../` to substitute and you also need to match the rest of the line in your regexp so the `.*` is needed or the old credentials are still in the output
- `-i` option on sed is needed for an in-place edit
- variable substitution is not performed in a string delimited with `'`, so changed to `"` here

Comment: ,the username displayed isn't proper. The password is correct. $USERN modifies the string username , dont know why . The echo of $USERN and $PWD are ',ername: 'cffde308-a1f8-436f-9750-619856e70b88
password: 'XEAstplhfKNAjUg2Z2oXjIe7o9D4VW3q2dtnkoiMEP0=',

Comment: Marking the solution as accepted. Along with the help of the below url. A dos2unix conversion of the source.txt help in the final result. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62125445/how-to-echo-encrypted-user-name-in-linux-concatenated-by-a-string-using-shell-sc?noredirect=1#comment109878468_62125445